# Rotate image on scroll, on a page with horizontal scroll and hidden scrollbars

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, events

So,there is no up and down scroll,just left and right. I have my scrollbars hidden, so onScroll event is not firing,instead I used *onWheel* event on App div in App.jsx.

Since pageXOffset returns 0,i don't know what property to use and make image rotate while scrolling.

This is my current code,i tried doing rotation with event properties in handleWheel, but it didn't work well.

Page structure of HomepageComponent

```
    <div>
     <div className='outer-wrapper'>
       <div className='wrapper'>
        <div className='slide one'>One</div>
        <div className='slide two'>Two</div>
        <div className='slide three'>Three</div>
        <div className='slide four'>Four</div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

App.jsx function and jsx

```
   function handleWheel(){
    const coffeeImg=document.getElementsByClassName('coffee')[0]

    coffeeImg.style.transform="rotate(" + window.pageXOffset/2 + "deg)"
    }

    return(
    <div className='App' onWheel={handleWheel}>
         <img className='coffee' src={coffee} alt="" />

      <AuthContextProvider>
        <RouterProvider router={router}/>
      </AuthContextProvider>
    </div>
    )
```

Css for scroll

```
    .wrapper{
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     width: 400vw;
     transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh); 
     transform-origin: top left;
    }
    .outer-wrapper{
     width: 100vh;
     height: 100vw;
     transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100vh);
     transform-origin: top left;
     overflow: scroll;
     overflow-y: scroll;
     overflow-x: hidden;
     position: absolute;
     scrollbar-width: none;
     -ms-overflow-style: none;
    }
```